how to render mdx in svelte
I'm building a blog using sveltekit + sqlite3, I want to store mdx content to database and render them dynamiclly
My solution is:

use mdsvex to compile .mdx to .svelte
use svelte to compile .svelte to .js

But saddly this doesn't work. here are my demo code:
/src/routes/test/+page.server.ts
import type { PageServerLoad } from "./$types"
import { mdsvex, compile } from "mdsvex";
import { compile as svelteCompile } from 'svelte/compiler';

export const load: PageServerLoad = async () => {
  const source = `
        <script>
          import Chart from '$lib/components/Chart.svelte';
        </script>
        
        # Hello friends
        
        <Chart />
        `;
  // md --> svelte
  const { code: transformed_code } = await compile(source, {
    extensions: ['.md', '.svx'],
    preprocess: mdsvex(),
  });
  console.log('compiled', transformed_code)

  // svelte --> js
  const { js } = svelteCompile(transformed_code, { generate: 'dom' });
  console.log('js', js.code);
  return { transformed_code: js.code };
}

/src/routes/test/+page.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    export let data;
</script>

{@html data.transformed_code}


It's hard to do ssr dynamiclly, my solution is compile the svelte components into web components, then use directly in markdown

The problem is that mdsvex is a Markdown preprocessor for Svelte components, thus acting at compile-time. Though it can be made use of in dynamic contexts, there are better solutions for this.
Something like svelte-markdown (based on Marked) that renders Markdown dynamically will do the job better here
